# Split Input for use with Bank Numbers (input split into sections)

Tags: php, html, yii

I do not seem to be able to find an answer for this, though likely I am looking at the wrong thing. I currently have a Yii application where I am able to create accounts and store peoples data. One such piece of data is a persons IBAN number.
Currently I have a single text input where people can type the country code and the 22 digits necessary. I am then able to validate this and error or save accordingly.
One thing I would like to do is to be able to have a split input box. In a single input an Iban appears like so:
ES0012345678912345678912

I would like to split it like so:
ES00 1234 5678 91 2345678912

This makes it much more user friendly and easy to read. I can certainly change the way it looks on the view but when editing I would like to have five input boxes in a single row, one takes 4, the next one 4 characters, the next one 4 etc. An example of what I mean:

[image]

Can someone please point me in the direction of how this is achieved. Is there a type of split input I can use, or do I need to create 5 separate inputs and simply join them on submission and validate from here? The ability to simply split the saved entry across these 5 boxes would be much easier.

Many Thanks

Comment: Do you use a model? `CActiveForm` or `CFormModel` or `CModel` ?

Comment: @AliMasudianPour the form I am working with uses `CActiveForm `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a suggestion, if you use a model, simply add your attributes like below:

```
Class ModelName extends CActiveRecord {
    public $ibanNumber;

    public $ibanNumberPart1;
    public $ibanNumberPart2;        
    public $ibanNumberPart3;
    public $ibanNumberPart4;

public function beforeValidate(){
    if(parent::beforeValidate()){
        $this->ibanNumber=$this->ibanNumberpart1.$this->ibanNumberPart2 ...
        return true;
    }    
}

//then write rules and so on
...}
```

By adding $ibanNumberPart1..4 properties to your model, it will know all of them as model attribute. So you can add 4 fields in your view with name `ibanNumberPart1` and so on. It is also possible to write validations rules for each attribute. For example:

```
public function rules(){
    return array(
        array('ibanNumberPart1','required'),
        array('ibanNumberPart1','numerical','integerOnly'=>true),
    );
}
```

By this, you split your input into 4 parts, and finally you have all of them into 1 field called `$ibanNumber`.

Comment: I feared this may be the way to go, although the solution here is much more elegant than what I had envisioned. I have not used `beforeValidate()` previously and can see about 100 different ways that can benefit me also. So many thanks you have shown me the way for the question I asked and helped me massively outside the scope of the question also. Many thanks

Comment: @TheHumbleRat You're welcome dear. I am so glad it helped you.